# Filter function as a data source for query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to use the output of Filter function as a data source for query function in order to produce pivot, based on part of the data?
The reason that I can not use the criteria in where clause of the Query is that the data for the criteria is in row, not in column.

Something like:
Query(Filter(A1:Q100;A2:Q2="Yes");"Select ... where ... pivot ...")

Notice that criteria is based on A2:Q2 row from all the data.

Or maybe there is some better approach to the problem, that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but then in the where clause string, you may have trouble referencing columns, as (I am guessing) the output of the FILTER function may be changing. You might need to expand on your particular use case to get advice on the best approach.